# How to copy value from any cell into same cell in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file where there are several sheets referring to the same data but showing different values.
For example: Sheet A shows time spent in MD and sheet B shows time spent in MY
What I want to do is when I enter a value in sheet A (say 100), I want it to appear in the same row/column in sheet B but divided by a specific value (let's say 200)

Is there an easy way to do this for any cell in the sheet?

Comment: You mean something like in Sheet2, Cell A1, have the following formula `=Sheet1!A1` so both cells have the same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy.  On the dependent sheet, enter your factor as follows:

```
=1/200*
```

...and before you hit ENTER on the keyboard, use the mouse to navigate to the first sheet (I'll call it Sheet1) and click the cell you want to divide by 200, let's say cell B2.  Now your formula should read,

```
=1/200 * 'Sheet1'!B2
```

Hit ENTER.

Now use fill down and fill right to populate the entire sheet with this formula, which will automatically change the cell reference to match whatever cell on the dependent sheet with an adjacent cell on Sheet1.

When you do this, you could write instead of B2, $B2, which will freeze the B column whenever you fill right or fill down.  Or B$2, which freezes row 2... or $B$2, which never changes when you fill right or fill down.

Cheers!

Comment: Great!  Thanks a lot! this will save me a lot of time :)